# How can I set/get a HashMap in a YAML configuration file?

Tags: yaml, minecraft, bukkit

I am making my first bukkit plugin. I would like to programmatically create a YAML file that represents a `HashMap`. How can I set and get this data structure?

The `HashMap` parameters look like `<Signature, Location>`, where `Signature` is my class that stores 4 integers, and `Location` is `org.bukkit.Location`

I think I would like the YAML file to look like this, but I am not sure if this structure is best:

```
MyPlugin:
    ListOfData:
        - signature: [1,2,3,4]    # this is a unique set of 4 integers
          location: [122,64,254]  # non-unique set of 3 integers
        - signature: [4,2,1,2]
          location: [91,62,101]
        - signature: [3,3,1,3]
          location: [190,64,321]
```

`Signature` can be modified as necessary, and I can create a wrapper for `Location` if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a suggested solution. I don't know if it is the best way...:)
You may want to consider this as your yaml structure:

```
MyPlugin:
    ListOfData:
        '[1,2,3,4]': '[122,64,254]'
        '[4,2,1,2]': '[91,62,101]'
        '[3,3,1,3]': '[190,64,321]'
        anothersignature:anotherlocation
        ...
```

This will let you read the "ListOfData" in using the normal technique for reading hash map from a YAMLConfiguration (see below).

You'll have to treat the incoming information from the file as a HashMap of <String, String> and do any translation (e.g. turn 122,64,254 into a location) you need from there.

For reading a HashMap:

```
this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("path.to.map").getValues(false)
```

For writing a HashMap (saveConfig() will still need to be called to write to disk):

```
this.getConfig().createSection("path.to.map", MyMap)
```

There's some details and subtleties here, its worth reading these carefully (same page, but different non-contiguous sections):

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps
http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps_2

Comment: My initial answer had a syntax error in the example YAML, I left out the quotes around the strings, and a space is required after the colon (:) in each HashMap pairing. I've corrected the text.

Comment: Some potential pitfalls: 1) since you're storing locations, consider whether you need to store a the world name in addition to the coordinates (to be multi-world compatible). 2) getConfigurationSection will return null if it can't find the specified sectionpath, so if you're not 100% certain the sectionpath will be there, you should do that step separately and check for null.

Comment: I decided to just create a wrapper and serialize the data (since it is not absolutely necessary that it be text-editable), but I will consider your answer for the future. Thank you!